# Erro no ./ executavel

Tags: c

Boa tarde, estou com esse erro na hora de compilar o programa:

> *** Error in `./executavel': realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000012d12f0 *** Aborted (imagem do núcleo gravada)

O meu programa copia de um arquivo para uma matriz alocada dinamicamente usando realloc pois não sei qual o tamanho de linhas e colunas da matriz de dentro do arquivo e depois a imprimi, o arquivo possui esse formato:

```
....*
*....
.....
.*...
.....
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* nome = NULL;
    char ch;
    FILE *arq = NULL;
    size_t tam;
    int counter = 1, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, l = 0, aux = 0;
    char** campo = NULL;

    getline(&nome, &tam, stdin);
    nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';


    arq = fopen(nome, "r");

    if(arq == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n");
    }
    else
    {
        while( (ch=fgetc(arq))!= EOF)
        {
            campo = (char**) realloc(campo, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));

            while(ch != '\n')
            {
                campo[i] = (char*) realloc(campo[i], (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
                campo[i][j] = ch;
                j++;
                aux = j;
            }

            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }

        for(k = 0; k < aux; k++)
        {
            for(l = 0; l < i; l++)
            {
                printf("%c ", campo[k][l]);
            }
            printf("\n");

        }           

    fclose(arq);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois do primeiro `realloc()`

```
    campo = (char**) realloc(campo, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
```

os novos ponteiros em `campo` têm um valor não especificado. Nomeadamente na primeira vez que essa instrução é executada (`campo` é NULL; `i` é zero) o `realloc` cria espaço para um ponteiro (`campo[0]`) mas não lhe atribui valor nenhum, deixando-o ficar com o lixo que existia no espaço de memória atribuído.

Mais abaixo, no loop seguinte, fazes

```
        campo[i] = (char*) realloc(campo[i], (i + 1) * sizeof(char));
        //                         ^^^^^^^^
```

que é inválido, pois `campo[0]` tem lixo.

Sugestão: usa `calloc()` que automaticamente inicializa a memória atribuido com zeros.